# Bootstrap 4 закрыть dropdown при клике по другому элементу

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Выпадающее меню в навбаре не закрывается, если кликнуть в область за ним. Как исправить?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown active">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drop_menu">Статьи</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu collapse" id="drop_menu">
        <li>
        <a id="activeLink" class="nav-link" href="incredibly_thick.html"><b>123</b></a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="giant_sequoias.html">345</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="really_bloodthirsty.html">678</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Статьи
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">345</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">678</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Для меню

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Статьи</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">123</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">345</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">678</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Видел подобные примеры в документации бутстрапа, но не могу приспособить к своему случаю. На сколько я понимаю разница в том, что в вашем примере выпадающее меню связано с кнопкой, у меня же это ссылка в навбаре.

Comment: Добавил еще один вариант

Comment: Понял в чем ошибка. data-toggle="collapse" должно иметь значение dropdown, но тогда слетает анимация) может быть знаете как использовать и то и то?)